# Get href or text attriburlte and place it in input filed

Tags: jquery, url, input

I've searched through many topics and all of them are for reverse order then what I need.

I have form with input field, and I want to grab link with specific class and place it's href attribute in input box. It can be href but it can also be text of a tag.

How can achieve that?

Comment: Please take the time to read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines (you may also need to read the advice on meta: '*[I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets," how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)*'

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attr` method.

Markup

```
<input type="text" id="hrefHere" />
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="google">Google Link</a>
```

jQuery

```
var hrefValue = $(".google").attr("href");
$("#hrefHere").val(hrefValue);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but quotes you've written were causing some issues so I've had to replace them.